# Do I need to subscribe to a topic every time I open the app again?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this case while using **firebase_messaging** with **Flutter**.

1. The first time, I install the app => I subscribed to a topic (ex: topic_1)
2. close app => open again
   3 => Do I need to subscribe to the topic (topic_1) every time I open the app again or only subscribe the first time the app is install?

And If I subscribed to the topic 2 times. Will I receive 2 notifications on my device?

Comment: Please your more details or Code

Comment: Oh, this case does not need more code to clear. I think It will be more confusing for everyone. It's how firebase_messaging works for subscribing to a topic. I just want to know if it saves the session for the topic when app close.

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason you subscribe to the same topic multiple times

> (e.g., calling subscribe To Topic more than once with the same topic name),

Firebase will only keep one subscription for that topic associated with the devices FCM token. Subscribing multiple times to the same topic does not result in multiple notifications being delivered to the device for the same message.

> In Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for Flutter, when you! subscribe to a topic using the firebase messaging package, you typically subscribe to a topic only once, and you don't need to subscribe to the same topic every time you open the app. Once you have subscribed to a topic, the subscription persists until you explicitly unsubscribe from it or the user uninstalls the app.

Comment: Could you kindly add from where you took those quotes? By a quick research I cannot find the exact page